# The intent passing one data twice(actually should pass 2 data)

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new in android and I just write a test app that should take the texts of the two buttons & change the text of them to each other in the new activity with intent.

but when I run the app and click the first button, it goes to second activity and in the second activity it just showing only the text of that button I just clicked on for both 2 buttons! actually, it should change the text of buttons to each other.(I mean the text of button 1 should display in button 2 and vice versa)

I check every question about the intent here, but my case is waired!!! because it seems everything is right! also, I check the code many times, I don't realize what's wrong!!!!

Thanks.

Here is the code:

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button buttonone,buttontwo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void changeText(View view){

    buttonone=(Button) view;
    buttontwo=(Button) view;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("button1text",buttonone.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("button2text",buttontwo.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myb.assignment.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="One"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonone"
    android:onClick="changeText"/>

<Button
    android:text="Two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttontwo"
    android:onClick="changeText"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonone"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

Button button1,button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    String intentData1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("button1text");
    String intentData2=getIntent().getExtras().getString("button2text");
    button1.setText(intentData2);
    button2.setText(intentData1);
}

}
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    />

<Button
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myb.assignment">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"> </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: just show us how you are finding the buttons by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity, in changeText(),

```
buttonone=(Button) view;
buttontwo=(Button) view;
```

These two lines assign the same button view, to both the buttons.
Insted of this, I recommend doing the following in your onCreate() method after setContentView();

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

And remove those two lines in changeText().

Comment: tnx :) it works! I can tell I check everything but I didn't accurate on that. tnx alot

Comment: Glad I could help :)